# incomplete type `std::string' when building OSDK on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi, dji-sdk

I am trying to build the DJI Onboard-SDK on a Raspberry Pi 4, and have had errors with different libraries missing that I have managed to resolve by installing those libraries. I've now gotten an error saying std::string isan incomplete type and printf is not declared. The only suggestions I've found say to install build-essentials, which I've already got installed and up to date. Can anyone give me suggestions about where to look next?

I've tried reinstalling g++ and ensuring all packages are up to date. I'm still getting the following errors in my make output;

```
[ 26%] Building CXX object osdk-core/CMakeFiles/djiosdk-core.dir/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp:4:
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/inc/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.hpp:23:15: error: field ‘currentLogFilePath’ has incomplete type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
   23 |   std::string currentLogFilePath;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iosfwd:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/memory:74,
                 from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/inc/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.hpp:13,
                 from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stringfwd.h:74:11: note: declaration of ‘std::string’ {aka ‘class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
   74 |     class basic_string;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp:15:39: error: ‘path’ has incomplete type
   15 | bool MmapFileBuffer::init(std::string path, uint64_t fileSize) {
      |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/iosfwd:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/memory:74,
                 from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/inc/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.hpp:13,
                 from /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stringfwd.h:74:11: note: declaration of ‘std::string’ {aka ‘class std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’}
   74 |     class basic_string;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp: In member function ‘bool DJI::OSDK::MmapFileBuffer::init(std::string, uint64_t)’:
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp:19:3: error: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope
   19 |   printf("Preparing File : %s\n", this->currentLogFilePath.c_str());
      |   ^~~~~~
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/Onboard-SDK/osdk-core/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp:7:1: note: ‘printf’ is defined in header ‘<cstdio>’; did you forget to ‘#include <cstdio>’?
    6 | #include <string.h>
  +++ |+#include <cstdio>
    7 |
make[2]: *** [osdk-core/CMakeFiles/djiosdk-core.dir/build.make:524: osdk-core/CMakeFiles/djiosdk-core.dir/modules/src/filemgr/impl/mmap_file_buffer.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:580: osdk-core/CMakeFiles/djiosdk-core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
```

Comment: What is the first error reported in your entire compilation output? It should be the first instance of the word "error". If the output is so large it scrolls beyond the screen, please redirect the output to a text file and search there.

Comment: @JohnFilleau - I've fed the output into a file as you suggested and searched through. The errors in the section I originally posted were the first errors to occur. Any idea how to resolve them?

Comment: Here's the full output: https://pastebin.com/vX9yL9bC

Comment: I don't have any experience with raspberry-pi or the dji-sdk, so unfortunately not. If they have a development forum I'd check there if you haven't already. I'm unfortunately not familiar with whatever toolchain they expect you to have.